# Why is there a peer1 hosting logo in Stack Overflow's footer?

Tags: support, footer

Why do stackoverflow place "peer1 host" on the footer near to cc-wiki logo?

[image: peer1 hosting logo]

I found the logo in stackoverflow.com and serverfault.com only. Is this something related with ad / sponsorship? If so why the logo is not there in other stackexchange sites?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/08/peer1-hosting-exclusive/ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptum_Technologies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can click on the PEER1 Hosting logo*:

[image]

<sub>(*It's clickable on the actual Stack Overflow page footer, not on the above image.)</sub>

Which gets you to [this page](http://www.peer1.com/stackoverflow):

[image]

The circled link on said page leads you to [a blog post written by a member of the SE team](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/peer1-hosting-exclusive/) that explains it:

> When we decided to move our Stack Exchange Network to the East Coast
> to better serve our global customers, PEER 1 Hosting was the logical
> choice because of the success that Fog Creek had. We began to migrate
> part of the data center in May of 2010, and finalized the move of all
> live sites from Oregon in October of 2010. After all the sites were
> set up at PEER 1 Hosting, we noticed some awesome results and thus we
> started a discussion with PEER 1 Hosting about how to extend the same
> benefits to the community.
>
> We think it’s a win-win!
>
> - As an advantage of being part of the community you get an awesome data
>   center at a discounted price – Win!
> - The more business Peer 1 Hosting does with people in the community, the
>   more support they can provide to power Stack Exchange – Win!

Basically, they found PEER1 to be a fantastic enough service to advertise it (for free?) via the footers on Stack Overflow and Server Fault. It doesn't show up on other sites probably because they are not of the demographic who would buy PEER1 hosting services (i.e. Cooking.SE, Home Improvement.SE, Bicycles.SE, etc).

Comment: i got it.... :)

Comment: Is it just me or is the sentence: `Stackoverflow.com and Serverfault.com users: Get no setup with any hosting plan!` badly worded? Especially if you omit the colon by fast reading...

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby I think I'd rather **get** setup, rather than **no** setup, with my hosting plan. Why advertise services I won't receive?

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby It _should_ read `No setup charge for any hosting plan!`, Marketing droids in the hosting industry are odd, odd birds.